# Unable to write file on physical device but the simulator works fine

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write a file to a folder (outside of the app) on iOS. I am using a `UIDocumentPickerViewController` to pick a folder, and creating a file under it. I'm basically following the official [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories):

```
guard folderUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
  print("Failed to obtain access to folder \(folderUrl)")
  return
}
defer { folderUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }

let fileUrl = folderUrl.appendingPathComponent("HelloWorld.txt")
guard fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
  print("Failed to obtain access to file \(fileUrl)")
  return
}
let fileData = "Hello World".data(using: .utf8)
try! fileData?.write(to: fileUrl)

fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

This all seems to work fine on a simulator. I can pick "On My iPhone" folder and the write is successful. However, when I try to run it on a physical device, it fails at `fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`.

What's even weirder is that, if I ignore the guard and continue with `try! fileData?.write(to: fileUrl)`, it doesn't throw an exception. It simply doesn't write anything to the folder.

The URLs I'm getting:

Simulator:

```
file:///Users/deling/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9173F102-09C7-474E-9040-6595CCBC9C4B/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/F13FAF79-B86B-496B-90C2-EA8D6F30FE53/File%20Provider%20Storage/
```

Physical iPhone:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/05C3ECD9-2601-4FD5-B2BD-D785A66DB952/File%20Provider%20Storage/
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: An app's sandbox is enforced on a real device but not on a simulator. There are many things that "work" in  simulator but will fail on a real device.

Comment: Hmm, is sandbox always enforced? As far as I can tell, my project doesn't have sandbox enabled. And I do not intend to ever ship it. It's a prototype for just a few people. Is there a way to get around it? Thanks.

Comment: All iOS apps are sandboxed. You can't change that.

Comment: The official doc says:

In iOS 13, users can select a directory from any of the available file providers using a UIDocumentPickerViewController.

Has that changed since iOS 13? I'm on 17.1

Comment: Argh... found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465021/permission-denied-when-trying-to-access-file-outside-of-ios-app-container

Looks like I can't even do that for debugging purposes. Oh well, I'll need to work around it then :(